# Ideatorrent open source alternative

Tags: open-source, project-management, project-planning

Are there any open source not drupal bundeled alternatives to the not very active Ideatorrent project?

Comment: I would also love to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

[Pligg](http://www.pligg.com/) is the only one which seems to have some voting features like IdeaTorrent although it looks to be more focussed on voting for stories than voting for ideas.

Perhaps a Pligg user can comment on its suitability as a replacement for IdeaTorrent?

Answer (score 1):

How about [BBYIDX](https://github.com/BBYOpen/BBYIDX), the tool behind [Best Buy IdeaX](http://bestbuyideax.com) that has been open sourced.

Comment: The Github link is dead. Did they cancel it being OS?

Answer (score 1):

OpenideaL, also a drupal based product, does exactly that: https://drupal.org/project/idea

Comment: Just a FYI for everyone: Last post is release of v2 from 2011.

Comment: The last OpenieaL version is only from two months ago, not from 2011. It dates to May 14th 2014.

Comment: FYI - A new release of OpenideaL is now available on https://drupal.org/project/idea

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking that if you added 'voting' to the open source KB software 68KB (http://68kb.com/) then you could use votes to add 'weight' to the KB articles and that would have the same effect.

KB articles would be 'ideas', and users can add comments and vote.